# How to save an Excel file and images in a .zip?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, asp.net-mvc

I have a table with carrier data and with the images of the DNI, and I need to download the table in excel format and the images within the same .zip. I can do both things separately without problem, but I'm having problems doing them together.

With this code I download the table with the carrier data:

```
using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection(conexion))
{
    consulta = 
    "SELECT entrega_tr, numTramite_tr, nombre_tr, apellido_tr, sexo_tr, documento_tr, ejemplar_tr, fechaNac_tr, fechaEmision_tr, cod_tr " +
        "from transportista WHERE entrega_tr = @entrega";
        
    cmd = new MySqlCommand(consulta, cn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@entrega", entrega);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cn.Open();

    using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        da.Fill(dt);
    }
}

dt.TableName = "Transportista";

using (XLWorkbook excel = new XLWorkbook())
{
    excel.Worksheets.Add(dt);

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        excel.SaveAs(stream);

       return File(stream.ToArray(), 
                   "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", 
                   "Transportista" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".xlsx");
    }
}
```

And with this I download the images:

```
consulta = "SELECT ImgFrenteDni_tr, ImgDorsoDni_tr from transportista WHERE entrega_tr = @entrega";
listaPedidos = TraerDirectoriosImagenesEntrega(consulta);

foreach (var lista in listaPedidos)
{
    var archivo_nombre = lista.getImgFrenteDni_tr();
    var archivo_arregloBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"wwwroot/" + lista.getImgFrenteDni_tr());
    zip.AddEntry(archivo_nombre, archivo_arregloBytes);

    archivo_nombre = lista.getImgDorsoDni_tr();
    archivo_arregloBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"wwwroot/" + lista.getImgDorsoDni_tr());
    zip.AddEntry(archivo_nombre, archivo_arregloBytes);
}
```

Both are inside a `using(ZipFile zip = new ZipFile()).`

My problem is when I want to save the Excel inside the .zip. I created a variable of type `var` so I can save the `File()` that I have to create Excel. But I cannot save this `var` variable (called "`excelTransportista`") inside the .zip, since it tells me it "cannot convert from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FileContentResult` to '`string`'".

I tried to convert `excelCarrier` to a `byte` array, but it still gives me the same problem:

```
System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(excelCarrier)
```

And this is how I would be creating and downloading the `.zip` if I could save them:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    excel.SaveAs(stream);

    //return File(stream.ToArray(), 
    //            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", 
    //            "Transportista" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".xlsx");

    var excelTransportista = File(stream.ToArray(), 
                                  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", 
                                  "Transportista" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".xlsx");
                                  
    zip.AddEntry("Transportista", excelTransportista);

    zip.Save(stream);
    bytes = stream.ToArray();
    return File(bytes, "application/zip", nombreZip);
}
```

Does anyone know?

**EDIT**

I will show the full code behind, perhaps someone can help

```
public FileResult DescargarDatosTransportista(string entrega)
        {
            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                string consulta;
                MySqlCommand cmd;
                List<PedidoViewModel> listaPedidos;
                byte[] bytes;
                string[] nombreImagen;
                MemoryStream output;

                using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
                {
                    consulta = "myQuery";
                    
                    listaPedidos = TraerDirectoriosImagenesEntrega(consulta);

                    foreach (var lista in listaPedidos)
                    {
                        nombreImagen = lista.getImgFrenteDni_tr().Split("/");
                        var archivo_nombre = nombreImagen[5];                        
                        var archivo_arregloBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("wwwroot" + lista.getImgFrenteDni_tr());
                        zip.AddEntry(archivo_nombre, archivo_arregloBytes);
                        nombreImagen = lista.getImgDorsoDni_tr().Split("/");
                        archivo_nombre = nombreImagen[5];
                        archivo_arregloBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("wwwroot" + lista.getImgDorsoDni_tr());
                        zip.AddEntry(archivo_nombre, archivo_arregloBytes);
                    }

                    var nombreZip = "Datos Transportista.zip";

                    using (MySqlConnection cn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=" + server + ";database=" + database + ";" + ";username=" + user + ";password=" + password + ";"))
                    {
                        consulta = "myQuery";
                        cmd = new MySqlCommand(consulta, cn);
                        
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        cn.Open();

                        using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {
                            da.Fill(dt);
                        }
                    }



                    dt.TableName = "Transportista";
                    using (XLWorkbook excel = new XLWorkbook())
                    {
                        excel.Worksheets.Add(dt);

                        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            excel.SaveAs(stream);

                            var excelTrans = File(stream.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Transportista" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".xlsx");
                            //
                            zip.AddFile(excelTrans.FileDownloadName);

                            zip.Save(stream);
                            bytes = stream.ToArray();
                            return File(bytes, "application/zip", nombreZip);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```